# Is it possible to view a user's questions in ascending order instead of descending order?

Tags: support, sorting

I want to create a permanent link to the most-downvoted questions that I've written, so that I can find out which of my own questions (and which specific types of questions) have the most downvotes. If I created a permanent link to my most-downvoted questions, then I could perhaps learn from my mistakes, and hopefully avoid any further damage to my Stack Overflow reputation. Is there an option to display questions in ascending order of popularity, instead of [descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=9), with the most-downvoted questions shown first, instead of the most-upvoted questions shown first? Is it currently possible to do this?

Comment: This should be trivial on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted [**a page that lists a user's questions by ascending score**](http://jsbin.com/asupeq/3).

Features:

- Uses the API to return results that are up-to-the-minute (excepting possible caching, by the API, on repeat requests)<sup>1</sup>.
- The results are fully (re)sortable and searchable.
- Can sort/search on almost every question field available in the API.
- Supports URL parameters for automatic searches.  EG:

  ```
  http://jsbin.com/asupeq/1?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=975097
  ```

Here's what [the page](http://jsbin.com/asupeq/3?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=975097) looks like for [the OP's current questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177227/anderson-green?tab=questions):

<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>
[image: screenshot]

---

<sup>1</sup> The API gets current data.  The *Data Explorer* (SEDE) data can be up to a month old.

Comment: +1 very cool! How about answers?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not possible right now short of using the data explorer [as Yannis mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179970/is-it-possible-to-view-a-users-questions-in-ascending-order-instead-of-descendi#comment545360_179970) or writing something using the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users).

Here's [a query to get you started](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113965):

```
select Score, CreationDate, Id as [Post Link]
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and OwnerUserId = ##userid##
order by Score asc
```

Once you plug in your userid, you can grab a permalink to the query that you can bookmark and revisit periodically to grab new results.

The obvious drawback, of course, is that the results can be out of date for up to a week, barring any issues that cause a delay in refreshing the data available through SEDE. Nor will this work for a site that's still in public beta, since those aren't available through the data explorer at all. Using the API would get around these limitations.